# Array of associate arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, list, hashmap, whmcs

```
  $postfields["pricing[1][annually]"] = "50.00";
  $postfields["pricing[1][monthly]"] = "50.00";
  $postfields["pricing[2][monthly]"] = "8.00";
  $postfields["pricing[2][annually]"] = "80.00";
```

I want something similar to the above variable in java. I am not talking about creating a class with required variables.

I have used `List<Map<String,String>> pricing = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();`
 but that doesn't seem to work with WHMCS api.

I debugged and came across this value on the back-end

```
 "pricing" -> "[{monthly=5.00, annually=50.00}]"
```

That is how it is done in the api:

http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Add_Product

Do we have anything similar in java that can cater this issue?
I am integrating a billing solution with WHMCS using their api.

Comment: You don't want to do that in Java; create the appropriate POJOs instead

Comment: @fge so you man a list of objects? how will it perform the mapping then?

Comment: The closest thing in java to associate arrays is HashMap afaik, so, sorry, but I still don't understand why this option doesn't work for you. Can you be a bit more specific bout it?

Comment: @solar the link i mentioned above has the example, I hope that you clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple 2D double array. You'll create some int constants for annually = 0, monthly = 1

```
double pricing = new double[][]{50.0, 50.0};
```

and so on